# Create observable and get observer in RXJS 5.0

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactivex

I am trying to work on my old project which is built with Angular2 beta1 and older RxJS. Now this code does not work:

```
    this.menuList = new Observable(observer => {
        console.log("test")
        console.log(observer)
    });
```

Closure with observer parameter is never executed.

What has changed?

Comment: you have to subscribe it

Answer (score 3):

The problem has nothing to do with you using an older version. The function you provide when constructing an `RxJS/Observable` only gets called when you subscribe to it.